# How to list down all aliases of Office365 account using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to list down all aliases of Office365 account using Microsoft Graph API? Is there a separate permission level I need to provide or different parameter in API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` to get the list of all aliases. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default alias is stored in `mailNickname` property. The full list of assigned aliases/addresses are stored in the `proxyAddresses` property collection. These include additional aliases *and* domains, so you may need do a little processing to split each address at `@` and dedupe the first element.

To retrieve these you would need to specifically request the properties you want using the `$select` query parameter:

```
/v1.0/me?$select=id,userPrincipalName,displayName,mailNickname,proxyAddresses
```

Using Graph Explorer's demo data, you would see this result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,userPrincipalName,displayName,mailNickname,proxyAddresses)/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "mailNickname": "MeganB",
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
    ],
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```